# after binding site ssl issues ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, why?

Tags: ssl, nginx, web, https, debian

On startssl.com I received a certificate. Nginx set up as follows:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name ***;
    location / {
        root /usr/html/***;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
 return 301 https://***$request_uri;
}

server {
   listen 433 ssl;
   server_name ***;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/nginx/***.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/nginx/***.key;

    location / {
        root /usr/html/***;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

}
```

When you attempt to visit the site of the browser issues:ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
[image]

What is my problem?

How to solve my problem?

Comment: This isn't the cause, but shouldn't you be listening on the default 443 port (not 433)?

Comment: you are right, thank you very much!

Comment: It's a pleasure! :)

Answer (score 0):

Set port 433, and 443 should be!